# Find the probability of a given output sequence in Tensorflow Seq2Seq?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

In Tensorflow seq2seq how can I calculate the probability of generation of a certain output sequence, given the seq2seq model and an input sequence?

Comment: Hi @RJK47, and welcome to Stack Overflow :) Just want to let you know that people on this site are not very inclined to answering theoretical questions (they would tell you to refer to the docs or previous questions). They'll readily help you if you have tried something out yourself, got stuck after researching, and show everything you've tried here, including links (if any), images (if any) and code (very important).

Answer (score 1):

You must be have read this paper. [Sequence to Sequence Learning with Neural Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf).
There is a math [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygjN2.png),
But in the Tensorflow seq2seq, logits is score of words. And you can get the probability of words by softmax. You can define a softmax function like this, softmax = lambda logits: np.exp(logits) / np.sum(np.exp(logiys), axis=0).
Next you can calculate the probability of output.
I've been thinking of doing that lately. If you have some good suggestion, please exchange with me, thanks a lot!